# Bus Error when running npm run dev || npm start

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, macos-monterey

I can't seem to run `npm run dev` or `npm start` on my macOS machine.
I get a **bus error** message every time I try to do so, and the output is usually something like this:

```
klvn git:(main) ✗ npm run dev

> klvn@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
[1]    1736 bus error  npm run dev
➜  klvn git:(main) ✗
```

I've tried removing the */node_modules*, *package-lock.json* and */.next* folders but that doesn't seem to help.
I'm running macOS Monterey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same error with a project I cloned from a repo.

My solution was to delete the local version of it and then clone it again. Then run an `npm install` and then the `npm run dev` script again.

Comment: This is exactly what I figured out in the end, and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 11):

The issues actually with `node_modules` and the `package-lock.json` file. Delete the following first:

- delete `node_modules` directory
- delete the `package-lock.json` file

And then run:

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

or any other `npm` command.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I got `zsh: bus error` IDK why but after I searched about bus error it says caused by Error Accessing, it means your Programs like "npm", "node", "nodemon", etc. can't get Access or even Accessed by Linux soo to fix it you only need to add sudo in your command

```
sudo npm install
```

Yeah and it works for me